# php file_get_contents doesn't return a value

Tags: php, json, api

I have a very simple piece of code which should return me a JSON object, but doesn't return any value.

When I access the url https://api.kraken.com/0/public/Time directly, you can see the desired JSON output.

However when calling the next function (on the url https://youreka-virtualtours.be/ethereum/functions.php?call=get_kraken), I don't get any output

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['call'])) {
        $error = '';
        switch($_GET['call']) {
            case 'get_kraken':
                    $url = 'https://api.kraken.com/0/public/Time';
                    $json = file_get_contents($url);

                    http_response_code(200);
                header('Content-Type: application/json');
                echo $json;
                break;
        }
    }
?>
```

Edit: Question: What am I doing wrong since the output of my file_get_contents differs from what the url https://api.kraken.com/0/public/Time shows

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Use curl instead of file_get_contents, to check response http code, that could help you debug where is the problem.

Comment: **I get** SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 3 of the JSON data

Comment: Your server might be blocked, I have no problems to get the json w/ file_get_contents. Additionally you don't have any error handling for that function, it is totally normal that it does not return a file (or URL) content but instead signals that the operation failed. You need to deal with both cases.

Comment: It is hard to tell what the problem is, but you can't echo a json object. Use `print_r($json)` and let me know if anything is returned?

Answer (score 0):

The code works fine, I tested it on local. This means that one of two things are happening. 1 : your server does not have the ability to make a file_get_contents call. 2 : your URL is incorrect, you really should echo something in case that happens. Try this to test :

```
<?php
    if(!isset($_GET['call']) || "get_kraken" !== @$_GET['call'] ) {
        echo "could not find a valid URL";
    }elseif (isset($_GET['call'])) {
        $error = '';
        switch($_GET['call']) {
            case 'get_kraken':
                    $url = 'https://api.kraken.com/0/public/Time';
                    $json = file_get_contents($url);

                    http_response_code(200);
                header('Content-Type: application/json');
                echo $json;
                break;
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: When saying it works fine, do you see the same output as you see when going directly to https://api.kraken.com/0/public/Time?